# Debug Stops When trying to Expand Items in List<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, visual-studio-debugging

For some reason, when I try to expand each item in the `_nodeDependencies` list which is an `IEnumerable<Node<T>>`, it shows there are 13 items but when I start expanding them it says it can't show me the content and evntually the debugger just bails after I click to many + to expand the items in the list.  I don't know if this is how Generics works during runtime or what.

```
public class Tree<T> where T : INode
{

    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _sourceDependencies;
    private IEnumerable<Node<T>> _nodeDependencies;
    public Node<T> RootNode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Node<T>, IList<Node<T>>> FlattenedMap { get; private set; }

    public Tree(T rootNode, IEnumerable<T> dependencies)
    {
        RootNode = new Node<T>(rootNode); 
        _sourceDependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public void BuildTree()
    {
        _nodeDependencies = ConvertDependenciesToNodes(_sourceDependencies);
        AddChildren();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Node<T>> ConvertDependenciesToNodes(IEnumerable<T> listToConvert)
    {
        IEnumerable<Node<T>> nodeList = listToConvert.Select(sourceNode => new Node<T>(sourceNode)).ToList();

        return nodeList;
    }
}
```

so meaning when I mouse over `_nodeDependencies = ConvertDependenciesToNodes(_sourceDependencies);`

`_nodeDependencies` says 13 items so I expand the list then try to expand one item or two items and it bails on me and stops debugging

[image]

Comment: `the debugger just bails` - not sure what you mean but if you are debugging iis site, it has default ping timeout for 90 seconds and stop process after this - which can look like bails )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doubtful that this has anything to do with the usage of Generics. It is much more likely the result of a timeout, as Lanorkin mentions.

What you might try in order to create a bit of a workaround - is to enhance what you are actually watching for in the Watch window, to drill down.

In other words, instead of (or in addition to) a watch on `_nodeDependencies`, try creating a watch on `_nodeDependencies[0]` and see what comes up. Continue this drill-down process until you get to the layer you're actually wanting to inspect.

The reason this can be useful (esp. when digging through things like `IQueryable` database results, or operating in a web-context) is that it takes *much* less time for the system to drill-down for you automatically than it takes for you to click through a series of results using the IDE - and therefore you get a better opportunity to see what you want prior to any kind of timeouts occurring.

Comment: yea it ended up being an error somewhere else or like you said a timeout but I don't usually get timeouts in VS.